# how to remove states from plotly Scattergeo trace?

Tags: python, plotly

I was reading through the Scattergeo documentation to remove Alaska and Hawaii from the 'usa' scoped without success. No functionality to access a specific subunit. Is there any workaround to perform this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this solved my issue. I had to superimpose a new trace. Take into account that the `marker_line_color` has to be set equal to your `paper_bgcolor`, once you got this, in order to avoid some aliasing between the `Cholorpleth` and the `Scattergeo`, set the `marker_line_width` to something bigger than the default value, e.g. 2.

```py
chorpleth = go.Choropleth(
        locationmode='USA-states',
        z=[0,0],
        locations=['AK','HI'],
        colorscale = [[0,'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'],[0,'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)']],
        marker_line_color='#fafafa',
        marker_line_width=2,
        showscale = False,
    )

fig.add_trace(chorpleth, row=1, col=1)
```

[image]